# Jquery passing variable to array in function

Tags: jquery, parameters

I have a small problem with a javascript variable that I cannot figure out. 
I am trying to pass a variable to a Jquery function parameter but it doesn't work.

Original code:

```
$(".bt-fs-dialog").fSelector({
  max: 25,
  excludeIds: [],
  getStoredFriends: [],
  closeOverlayClick: true,

});
```

Now I want to pass values to the getStoredFriends field.
The documentation says it should be added like this: 
getStoredFriends: [12345678,5484545],

So this is what I do:

```
var testresponse = "193102451,731800273";

$(".bt-fs-dialog").fSelector({
  max: 25,
  excludeIds: [],
  getStoredFriends: testresponse,
  closeOverlayClick: true,

});
```

This doesn't work. No values are added to the function. I also tried to pass the values as an array:

```
var testresponse = new Array();
testresponse[0] = "193102451";
testresponse[1] = "731800273";

$(".bt-fs-dialog").fSelector({
  max: 25,
  excludeIds: [],
  getStoredFriends: testreponse,
  closeOverlayClick: true,

});
```

This also doesn't work. 
Can anyone explain how I can pass the values to this function?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is that `fSelector` ?

Comment: For reference, OP seems to be using [Facebook Friend Selector](http://facebook-friend-selector.codersgrave.com/).

Comment: Yes, sorry I forgot to mention. I am using Facebook Friend Selector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[12345678,5484545]` is an array of numbers, so that's probably what expects this function.

Try with

```
var testresponse = []; // better than new Array()
testresponse.push(193102451); // using push you don't have to specify the index
testresponse.push(731800273);
```

Comment: Or just `var testresponse = [193102451, 731800273];`. You don't actually need a variable either, you can throw that array literal straight in the object literal.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
var testresponse = [193102451,731800273]

This should work

testresponse[0] will give 193102451 and testresponse[1] will give 731800273